# how use tests written in Selenium and Cucumber-JVM with JMeter?

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, jmeter, cucumber-jvm

I have set of functional tests written in Selenium and Cucumber-JVM, I use maven to run them by Cucumber tags.

Now I need to use some of those tests with JMeter to check performance. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can just

1. Compile your tests into .jar file(s)
2. Copy the .jar file(s) into JMeter classpath

   - tests files - under /lib/junit folder of your JMeter installation
   - dependency files - under /lib folder
3. Add [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) Sampler and choose required test from "Classname" and "Test Method" dropdowns
4. Configure JMeter as per your load scenario and run the test

See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide for details on working with JUnit tests from JMeter perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter sampler called [BSF Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Sampler). This one allows to execute java class from JMeter. Please choose beanshell in the scripting language field.