# Does JMeter support performance test for UI

Tags: java, jmeter, cucumber, cucumber-java

I run automation test by selenium and cucumber.
Now I want to integrate selenium and cucumber with JMetter to test performance for UI. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198467/how-use-tests-written-in-selenium-and-cucumber-jvm-with-jmeter?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

To test performances of Browser UI, you can use selenium web driver plugin that can be installed with jmeter-plugins manager/

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/

See:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/

Answer (score -1):

if you extract the selenium web driver test as a Jar file you can they use jmeter to run this as a junit test (browserless). more info :[Use Selenium WebDriver JUnit with JMeter](http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/performance-test-menu/selenium-load-test-menu/175-use-selenium-webdriver-junit-with-jmeter)

Also this question has been asked before: [how use tests written in Selenium and Cucumber-JVM with JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198467/how-use-tests-written-in-selenium-and-cucumber-jvm-with-jmeter)

Comment: I was being more explicit in the answer - to how it actually worked as i find that more useful then just theirs a plugin (if you find that "not useful nor correct" then thats your view I am sure other people may find this useful) Also i would be happy being told something twice if one is point me in the right direction and other is tell me how it works. two similar answers is better then just down marking peoples answers